# Which command to use to create a new branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

What's the difference between: `git branch <branchname>` and `git checkout -b <branchname>`, don't they both create a new branch?

Comment: Did you mean `git checkout -b <branchname>`? The `-f` flag is not related to branch creation.

Comment: Yes @alfunx, that was my typo in my notes, should have been -b not -f. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `git branch` - See what branches are there and what's you're working on right now
- `git branch new_branch_name` or `git branch new_branch_name HEAD` - Create new branch. Use letters, numbers and underscores as best practice. Branch created from the commit currently HEAD looking into on the current working branch
- `git checkout new_branch_name` - Switch to other branch. HEAD will still look to same hash until new commit is done then HEAD moves accordingly. When switching branches, all files and folders are changing to match that branch immediately.
- `git checkout -b new_branch_name` - Create new branch and switch to it at once

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the typo, I think my notes should have read "git checkout -b <branchname>" instead of "-f". So the basic difference in the two commands is that the latter command not only creates the new branch but it switches to it as well. Very helpful!

Comment: @AmandaRueda Yes exactly. Typo is edited so no worries and welcome to Stackoverflow after some years of the answer :)